# Prove that this graph with 20 edges on 11 vertices is not 3-colorable.

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, graph-theory, coloring

> Let $G$ be the graph with $11$ vertices labeled $0, 1, 2,..., 10$ and $20$ edges
> $$(1, 2),(2, 3),(3, 4),(4, 5),(5, 1),\\
> (1, 7),(2, 8),(3, 9),(4, 10),(5, 6),\\
> (1, 10),(2, 6),(3, 7),(4, 8),(5, 9),\\
> (0, 6),(0, 7),(0, 8),(0, 9),(0, 10).$$
> Prove that $G$ is not $3$-colorable.

I have tried to find the clique number to show that the lower bound is at least $4$; however, the largest clique I could find was on $2$ vertices, so that was not a helpful strategy. I then tried to find that the independence number was less than $3$ so that
$$\chi(G)\geq \frac{|V|}{\alpha(G)}$$
where $\alpha(G)$ is the independence number. Again, however, I found an independent set on $4$ vertices, that of $\{2,5,7,10\}$, so I am nowhere closer to proving what I'm supposed to. Any help would be great!

Comment: What do you color? Edges or vertices?

Comment: by definition of a proper coloring, vertices

Comment: Have you drawn the graph?

Comment: yes, I used it to help me find independent sets and cliques

Comment: Hint: It is the [Grötzsch graph](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gr%C3%B6tzsch_graph). Also see the [Mycielskian graph construction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mycielskian).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I suggested in the comments; this graph is the [Grötzsch graph](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gr%C3%B6tzsch_graph). It is triangle free and its independence number is $5$. Here's a nicely symmetric drawing of the graph, with vertex $i$ labeled $v_i$:

[image]

Suppose the graph is $3$-colorable, with colors $1$, $2$ and $3$. Let $c_i$ denote the color of $v_i$. First note that the five vertices of the inner star cannot all be the same color, so without loss of generality $c_2\neq c_5$. Relabeling the colors and reflecting we may assume that $c_0=1$, $c_6=2$, $c_5=1$ and $c_2=3$. Then necessarily $c_8=2$, and continuing along the outer star we find that $c_4=3$ and then $c_{10}=2$, and now $v_1$ cannot be colored.